# Cuando usar el tag # en un input text?

Tags: angular

He visto que en angular 2 en vez de usar ngModel puedo poner algo como esto:

```
<input type="text" name="txtnombre" #Nombre />
<button (click) = "validarNombre(#Nombre)" > Validar </ button>
```

No logro entender bien cuando se debe usar este tipo de variable con # y cual es la ventaja de usar esto en vez de esto

```
<input type="text" name="txtnombre" [(ngModel)]="nombre" />
```

Me podrían alguien explicar? gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresion `#nombre` sobre un elemento html crea la referencia sobre el elemento. Por ejemplo cuando haces:

```
<button (click) = "validarNombre(#Nombre)" > Validar </ button>
```

Se esta enviando la referencia del elemento html llamado `#Nombre`, en este caso el input.

Ahora bien, una razon valida por la que quizas quieras hacer esto es para minimizar el uso de bindings en angular en caso de no ser necesario. Si utilizaras en `ngModel`, angular tendria que hacer el binding para observar los cambios en el `input` pero con la referencia del elemento eso no es necesario. Sin embargo, no es bueno realizar operaciones de modificación sobre elemento con la referencia del mismo a menos de ser necesario ya que para eso angular dispone de una amplia  variedad de directivas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ahora me a quedado claro!! No te doy respuesta aceptada porque mi reputación no lo permite. Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Ya apendri como aceptar una respuesta, puse aceptada tu respuesta...